# strcpy issue with structure in C

Tags: c, strcpy

The content of course.Code before and after strcpy(course.Name, b) is "This" and "Thisis", which seems like strcpy() is also concatenating the content of b to course.Code

```
typedef struct {
    char Code[4];
    char Name[2];
}Course;

int main() {
    char str[7] = "This is";
    char a[4], b[2];
    Course course;
    sscanf(str, "%s %s", a, b);
    strcpy(course.Code, a);
    printf( "%s\n", course.Code );
    strcpy(course.Name, b);
    printf( "%s\n", course.Code );
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: You'd better hope nobody enters more than 3 characters for `Code` or 1 character for `Name`.

Comment: it's just my simple way to depict the situation, but thanks for reminding

Answer (score 3):

You need five characters to store "This" and three to store "is" because each string is terminated by a zero. (Bonus point: You need eight to store "This is")

The raw memory in `course` is going to look like this:

```
Code[0] 'T'
Code[1] 'h'
Code[2] 'i'
Code[3] 's'
Name[0] 'i'
Name[1] 's'
```

Since there is no terminating zero on `course.Code`, `printf` will keep printing. It has no way of knowing you wanted it to stop after four characters. The fact that you didn't get unreadable garbage after "Thisis" is largely a matter of luck and/or compiler settings.

Comment: Note also that it is not guaranteed that the storage for the `Name` member abuts the end of the storage for the `Code` member, although the observed behavior seems to show that in this case it does.  The structure layout can include any amount of padding after each member.

Comment: @JohnBollinger That's a good point. If there _was_ any padding between the structure members, `strcpy(course.Code, a);` would have copied the terminating zero _into the padding_ and tungts might never have noticed any unusual behavior.

Comment: ... and this is but one reason why overwriting array bounds produces undefined behavior.